# Validar datos con expresiones regulares en QT C++

Tags: c++, qt

espero me puedan ayudar con este problema, necesito validar una cadena de caracteres usando expresiones regulares en QT C++, el problema que tengo es que la función `match(user).isValid()` siempre me está retornando `true`, alguien me puede decir que pueda estar pasando??? Gracias

```
QString patron = "[a-zA-Z0-9]+";
QRegularExpression *validador = new QRegularExpression(patron);
bool valido = validador->match(user).isValid();
if(valido){this->usuario = user;}
```

Comment: ¿Qué cadenas has probado?

Comment: "pepe" y similares y "·/$·#" caracteres no alfanuméricos.

Answer (score 0):

No tienes que preguntar por `isValid` sino por `hasMatch`:

```
bool valido = validador->match(user).hasMatch();
```

Aunque para validar **todo** el usuario, es decir, que no haya caracteres extraños ni al principio ni al final ni en el medio, debes incluir un par de modificadores:

```
QString patron = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
```

`^` sirve, en este caso, para anclar el patrón al inicio de la cadena, mientras que `$` hace lo propio con el final de la cadena. Dicho de otra forma: `^...$` va a validar la cadena de entrada al completo.

Adicionalmente, fíjate que no es necesario crear de forma dinámica el objeto `validador`. Piensa que si se te olvida hacer el `delete` correspondiente acabarás teniendo fugas de memoria y eso no es algo deseable:

```
QRegularExpression validador(patron);
bool valido = validador.match(user).hasMatch();
```

Comment: Gracia hermano, tu solución la voy a emplear para encontrar subcadenas, mi problema ya lo había resuleto de esta manera:
`
QRegExp patron = ("[a-zA-Z0-9]+");
bool valido = patron.exactMatch(user);
if(valido){this->usuario = user;}
`
Gracias de todas maneras, te lo agradezco bastante